# Iphone: Need release using ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

i have one simple question, if i'm using ASIFormDataRequest when i need to release the request object?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];
ASIFormDataRequest *requestForm = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[requestForm addPostValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"user"] forKey:@"user"];
[requestForm setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[requestForm setDelegate:self];
[requestForm startAsynchronous];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search in the implementation file shows that it'll be autoreleased.

```
+ (id)requestWithURL:(NSURL *)newURL
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithURL:newURL] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remember that you are always responsible for releasing an object if the method from which you receive it contains `new`, `copy`, or `init`.

In this case, you don't need to release it. The `ASIHTTPRequest` class `autorelease`s it for you.

Comment: So if i use:
NSPredicate *eventPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:          @"(event == %@)", [item objectForKey:@"event"]];
[eventRequest setPredicate:eventPredicate];

I don't need to release predicate, am i right?

Comment: Correct. That rule is always true. Remember to √ my answer if you believe it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your request is autoreleased in your code, so you don't need to release it (as others have said).

However, you are starting an asynchronous request - it'll complete/fail sometime in the future, and if it is associated with other objects which will get freed when the view exits you're potentially leaving yourself open to a crash. So I'd suggest you would want to make requestForm a property of your class (so when you assign the request to self.requestForm it will get retained for you), and explicitly release & nil it when the request completes.

If it's a very simple app with just one view you may get away without that though.